# Java is asking to return a value even when the value is returned in the if-else ladder

Tags: java, if-statement, return

I was trying to code AVL tree in java and something has just shaken my understanding of basic programming. Why does Java force me to return a value when I already have a return statement in the else block of the if-else ladder. I tried debugging and it works as expected, it never goes to the returns statement outside the if-else blocks. I have been working on java and never realized this.  I am not even sure if this was always there or is it something new? I also read a few blogs which say that you don't have to return a value if you have returned it from the else block.

```
The error which I get is I skip the last return statement.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    This method must return a result of type AVLNode
```

https://javahungry.blogspot.com/2019/12/missing-return-statement-in-java.html
checkout the last example on this link.

```
public class AVL 
{
    AVLNode root;
    
    private AVLNode insert ( AVLNode current,int val)
    {
        if ( current == null)
        {
            return new AVLNode(val, 0, null, null);
        }
        else if ( val < current.val)
        {
            current.left = insert ( current.left, val);
        }
        else if ( val > current.val)
        {
            current.right = insert ( current.right, val);
        }
        else
        {
            return current;
        }
        return current;     // I don't want to return you ////      
    }


public void  add ( int val)
    {
        this.root = insert ( this.root, val);
    }
```

Comment: get rid of `else
        {
            return current;
        }`

Comment: If you declare a method to return something it has to do it in all execution paths. You can't have it return some value if some condition is met and don't return anything in other cases.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer... Why the program allows skipping the return statement if it is only if-else and I return value in both blocks but does not allow the same with an if-else ladder. How are they different?

Comment: Why would someone give a downtick to this, I researched, I tried to read and even shared one of the blogs I tried debugging the answer just didn't click to me. I guess I fulfilled the basic criteria of not asking a bad question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get this error is because if you didn't have the final `return` statement, and ended up inside one of the `if` blocks, you'd never hit the `else` and therefore never hit a `return` statement.

Try stepping through the code with any case where `current.val` and `val` are both specified, but are two different values, for example `current.val = 2` and `val = 1`.

In this case the execution will skip over the first `if` (because `current` is not `null`), and then go into the second `if` block (because `val > current.val`). Because one of the `if` conditions has been met, we will skip over the following `else if` and the `else`, and hit the final `return` statement. If that statement weren't there, we'd never return anything.

The reason this is different from the example you cite is because that example has a `return` in both the `if` and the `else` blocks, so whatever happens you always encounter a `return` statement. You could achieve the same by adding `return current;` inside both `else if` blocks, although it's far cleaner just to have the single return at the end.

Basically, if you have a collection of `if...else if...else if...else` the execution will only ever visit one of the blocks. Whichever path through the code gets executed must always have a `return`.

Comment: Hey, I guess I conveyed my question in the wrong way.. I'll try and edit it.
Why the program allows skipping the return statement if it is only if-else and I return value in both blocks but does not allow the same with an if-else ladder. How are they different?

Comment: Hey, I got it... Just couldn't think that way. Thanks a lot, I am at peace now :D.

Answer (score 1):

you either use

else

```
    {
        return current;
    }
```

or

```
    return current;
```

so in my opinion your "if-else" is a conditional way to set the correct value for the variable "current" so using "else" for returning purposes is kind of strange,so you code can be refactored as this: use the if-else to catch all possible cases in the condition, set the variable in ever case and then, when you are done,  return the value, like:

```
private AVLNode insert ( AVLNode current,int val)
{
    if ( current == null)
    {
        return new AVLNode(val, 0, null, null);
    }
    else if ( val < current.val)
    {
        current.left = insert ( current.left, val);
    }
    else if ( val > current.val)
    {
        current.right = insert ( current.right, val);
    }
         
    return current;     
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer... Yes, I did that and moved on but the question is bothering me. Why the program allows the return statement if it is only if-else and I return value in both blocks but does not allow the same with an if-else ladder. How are they different?

Answer (score 0):

One of the principle of Clean code is `method should have only one return statement` so even if your code is good and working you could do it would be better if you do something like this

```java
private AVLNode insert ( AVLNode current,int val)
    {
       AVLNode returningObject = current;

        if ( current == null) {
            current = new AVLNode(val, 0, null, null);
        } else if ( val < current.val) {
            current.left = insert ( current.left, val);
        } else if ( val > current.val) {
            current.right = insert ( current.right, val);
        }
   
        return returningObject ;       
    }
```

And that solve the issue with   `// I don't want to return you ////`

But you problem appears cause Java is `smart enough` to check all your statements before you run your code, and if you put all your `returns` into block statements `Java knows` that there is situation where your statements can be not achieved and force you to always return something from the method.

This is the simplest way I can explain it.

Answer (score 0):

All of your recursive calls to `insert ()` sooner or later end up on one of the branches which contain a `return` (or let's assume that for the sake of the discussion).
I think that your misconception is that this is enough.
But each level of recursive call has to get its own `return`.

So these two lines

```java
current.left = insert ( current.left, val);
/* ... */
current.right = insert ( current.right, val);
```

each also need a `return`, in order to return from the level which did the calling, the implied `return` at the deepest nested recursive call level is only for that level.

Answer (score 0):

And not just for Java, either. When you have a nested structure like the one in the OP, when it matches the first 'if' and starts down your nested if-then-else-if ladder, then it is **never** going to somehow fall through to the 'else' that matches the top-level 'if' statement because it has already evaluated that condition and chosen its execution path.

The conditions you are testing for are independent and unconnected, so there is no need for the `else` construct at all. Once we have dealt with the null case and returned a new AVLNode, they are just simple unconnected `if` statements that conditionally modify the state of `current`.

```java
private AVLNode insert ( AVLNode current, int val) {

   if (current == null) {
      return new AVLNode(val, 0, null, null);
   }

   if (val < current.val) {
      current.left = insert(current.left, val);
   }

   if (val > current.val) {
      current.right = insert(current.right, val);
   }

   // nothing changes when val == current.val, is this correct?

   return current;      
}
```